# Form data from JQuery dynamic form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I got the jquery part of the jquery dynamic form from this website http://code.google.com/p/jquery-dynamic-form/ working great. Now I can't for the life of me, figure out how to get the form data into an email using PHP. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: This can be broken down into a couple different questions which you can probly find specific help on easily, namely -form processing in php & -sending emails with php.

Comment: That is a seriously open-ended question. It almost sounds like you need to learn PHP, which this site can't really help you with. If you know PHP, then you need to read this on how to send an email: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the data from the nested array.

Comment: @Steve Then why did not you ask that? Show the necessary code details and explain what you're trying to do and where you have a problem (maybe open a new question). We do not have time to find out what you are trying to ask, but we are happy to help if you have a specific question.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, sorry I should have been more detailed. Tim Bolton actually pointed me in the correct direction and I got it figured out.  I got the form data to send an email and write to a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `print_r($_REQUEST);`, to see what's being sent on the form.  From there, you'll know how to access it.